# Airflow Webserver UI not loading

Tags: amazon-ec2, airflow, airflow-webserver

I have two instances of airflow running on two separate EC2 instances. One is a production environment that has the url: `airflow.company.com:8080`.

On production my `airflow.cfg` looks like:

```
[webserver]
# The base url of your website as airflow cannot guess what domain or
# cname you are using. This is used in automated emails that
# airflow sends to point links to the right web server
base_url = https://airflow.company.com:8080

# The ip specified when starting the web server
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0

# The port on which to run the web server
web_server_port = 8080

# Paths to the SSL certificate and key for the web server. When both are
# provided SSL will be enabled. This does not change the web server port.
web_server_ssl_cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/airflow.company.com/cert.pem
web_server_ssl_key = /etc/letsencrypt/live/airflow.company.com/privkey.pem

# Number of seconds the webserver waits before killing gunicorn master that doesn't respond
web_server_master_timeout = 120

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
web_server_worker_timeout = 120
```

The other im trying to get to load on `airflowtest.company.com:8081` but its not working.
The airflow.cfg here looks like:

```
[webserver]
# The base url of your website as airflow cannot guess what domain or
# cname you are using. This is used in automated emails that
# airflow sends to point links to the right web server
#base_url = http://localhost:8080
base_url = https://airflowtest.company.com:8081

# The ip specified when starting the web server
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0

# The port on which to run the web server
web_server_port = 8081

# Paths to the SSL certificate and key for the web server. When both are
# provided SSL will be enabled. This does not change the web server port.
web_server_ssl_cert =
web_server_ssl_key =

# Number of seconds the webserver waits before killing gunicorn master that doesn't respond
web_server_master_timeout = 120

# Number of seconds the gunicorn webserver waits before timing out on a worker
web_server_worker_timeout = 120
```

In the second instance I have my outbound setup like so:

[image]

The custom source above is my own IP address for my machine.

I've tried deleting the `airflow-webserver.pid` and `airflow-scheduler.pid` and then running with `pipenv run airflow initdb && pipenv run airflow webserver -D && pipenv run airflow scheduler -D`.

With `sudo lsof -i tcp:8081` I can see the processes running on port 8081

```
COMMAND       PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gunicorn: 3248923 ubuntu    5u  IPv4 3412762      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)
[ready]   3361698 ubuntu    5u  IPv4 3412762      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)
[ready]   3362434 ubuntu    5u  IPv4 3412762      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)
[ready]   3363152 ubuntu    5u  IPv4 3412762      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)
[ready]   3363808 ubuntu    5u  IPv4 3412762      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)
```

A `wget 0.0.0.0:8081` returns a 200 success code:

```
--2023-10-11 22:32:43--  http://0.0.0.0:8081/
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 FOUND
Location: http://0.0.0.0:8081/home [following]
--2023-10-11 22:32:43--  http://0.0.0.0:8081/home
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 FOUND
Location: http://0.0.0.0:8081/login/ [following]
--2023-10-11 22:32:43--  http://0.0.0.0:8081/login/
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7554 (7.4K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

index.html.1                               100%[======================================================================================>]   7.38K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2023-10-11 22:32:43 (1.20 GB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [7554/7554]
```

But when I try to navigate to 0.0.0.0:8081 OR airflowtest.company.com:8081 in my browser nothing loads. Is there something else I'm missing or need to configure?